# Facebook Graph API keeps reloading after login on iPhone 4s

Tags: javascript, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to use Facebook Graph API to login on my website. It's working fine on the four different iPhone 4 (running iOS 5) and the one iPhone 5 (running iOS 5) device I've tested with.

On the iPhone 4s (running iOS 5) device, it keeps reloading the the facebook page after I've typed in my credentials on Facebook and clicked login.

This is a screenshot of how the page looks, when it keeps reloading:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Here's the Facebook login code I'm using:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status == "connected") {
        // do something
      }
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe("auth.login", function(response) {
      if (response.status == "connected") {
        // do something
      }
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        // do something
      }
    });
  };

  function loginUser() {
    FB.login(function(response) { }, {});
  }
  function logout() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
      // do something
    });
  }
  (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="loginUser(); return false;">Login</a>
```